# Controlling Parameter Slurping

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to write a grammar that supports functions calls without using parentheses:

```
f x, y
```

As in Haskell, I'd like function calls to minimally slurp up their parameters. That is, I want

```
g 5 + 3
```

to mean

```
(g 5) + 3
```

instead of

```
g (5 + 3)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the second parse with this grammar:

```
grammar Parameters;

expr
  : '(' expr ')'
  | expr MULTIPLICATIVE_OPERATOR expr
  | expr ADDITIVE_OPERATOR expr
  | ID (expr (',' expr)*?)??
  | INT
  ;

MULTIPLICATIVE_OPERATOR: [*/%];
ADDITIVE_OPERATOR: '+';

ID: [a..z]+;
INT: '-'? [0-9]+;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

The parse tree I'm getting is this:

[image: Not the parse tree I want]

I had thought that the subrule listed first would get attempted first. In this case, `expr ADDITIVE_OPERATOR expr` appears before the `ID` subrule, so why is the `ID` subrule taking higher precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case ANTLR does not the correct rule transformation (to eliminate left recursion and to handle precedences):

```
expr
    : expr_1[0]
    ;

expr_1[int p]
    : ('(' expr_1[0] ')' | INT | ID (expr_1[0] (',' expr_1[0])*?)??)
      ( {4 >= $p}? MULTIPLICATIVE_OPERATOR expr_1[5]
      | {3 >= $p}? ADDITIVE_OPERATOR expr_1[4]
      )*
    ;
```

leading to `(expr (expr_1 a (expr_1 5 + (expr_1 3))))`

**correct would be:**

```
expr
    : expr_1[0]
    ;

expr_1[int p]
  : ('(' expr_1[0] ')' | INT | ID (expr_1[5] (',' expr_1[5])*?)??)
  ( {4 >= $p}? MULTIPLICATIVE_OPERATOR expr_1[5]
  | {3 >= $p}? ADDITIVE_OPERATOR expr_1[4]
  )*
  ;
```

leading to `(expr (expr_1 a (expr_1 5) + (expr_1 3)))`

I am not certain if this is a bug in ANTLR4 or a trade-off of the transformation algorithm. Perhaps one should write an issue to the ANTLR4 jira.

To solve your problem you can simply put the correctly transformed grammar into your code and it should work. The explanation of rule transformation is found in "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference" on pages 249ff (and perhaps somewhere on the web).

Comment: Manually eliminating left recursion sounds like the way to go. I've been confused by a couple other issues with it and I think I'd like to better understand the magic that ANTLR performs on my behalf.

Comment: Is there a way to generate and view the transformed grammar? More importantly, how do labels like `# Additive` get mixed in if I manually transform my left-recursive rules as you describe? Is labeling still possible?

Comment: The command line option -Xlog should log the transformed grammar (according to the book). I do not think that labeling works with those compact grammars. But if manually eliminating the leftrecursion is your way it should be easy to rewrite this grammar in a way that labels are appliable.

Comment: I've submitted this to ANTLR's issue tracker: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/866.